# How to remove flashlight from iPhone X lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

The iPhone X lock screen has two default buttons, one is Camera and other is flashlight. Is there any way to remove/customize the flashlight shortcut? I could not find any solution for it anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On iOS 11 - the flashlight is tied to the 3D Touch feature. If you turn that off in General> Accessibility>3D Touch, then the flashlight disappears.

On iOS 12 - there's no known way to remove this with a setting on the phone or action short of jailbreaking (which would be a different question entirely on how to jailbreak)

Comment: It looks like this is no longer the case on iOS 12, so it appears to be impossible to disable now :(

Comment: Aw, that shucks on iOS 12. I was just searching for a solution. I find myself turning on the flashlight on my iPhone XS Max when I'm reaching for it in my pocket. :s

Comment: My flashlight used 39% of battery today, probably because I turned it on while getting my phone out of my trousers. Shame you can’t turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

This has been removed on iOS 12. You can no longer remove the flashlight and camera icon on iOS 12 on the homescreen by disabling 3D Touch.